# How can I update the data on my listview using AsyncTask in android?

Tags: android

I am a newbie here, and I have searched online (and on stackoverflow) for the answer but I am still struggling to make it work.

What I am trying to do, is (1) update my list with fresh "posts" using an asyncronous task - thus allowing the user to continue using the app as I download new posts to their android.

I am struggling to get the updating task to work, and it could be tied to an obvious implementation problem (or not).

What I have is (1) A customized list (it allows "pull to refresh" - but as stated it is a problem that it is not refreshing any data at this point).  (2) a custom AsyncTask that will theoretically populate more posts for the main list on the main screen.

Here is problem point in the list:

```
listView.setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefreshListView.OnRefreshListener(listView) {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            mylistAdapter.loadNewData(); //loads new data <-------------------
```

m_ptrlistView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

```
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m_ptrlistView.onRefreshComplete();
                }
            }, 2000);
```

////////////
Here is the function "loadNewData" in the adapter

```
public void loadNewData(PullToRefreshListView List){

    //load new stuff
    new AsyncFetchMore(list).execute();

    // MANDATORY: Notify that the data has changed
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    return;
}
```

And... my asyncTask that is extended's implementation

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground() {

    try {
        //simulating a long task
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.d("Notes", "Thread failed to sleep");
    }

    //create dummy posts for testing
    for ( int i = 12; i < 24; i++ ) {
        Post pNewPost = new Post();
        pNewPost.setText("POST # " + i);
        m_alNewPosts.add(pNewPost);
    }

    return null;
}
```

///////////////////////////////

Perhaps I'm approaching it all wrong.  I'm having doubts... But I just don't know what the right next step is and I am pretty lost here!  Can you give me any tips?

Comment: if any of the answers helped you out, please accent the one that helped you out the most as the correct one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you arent doint anything with results that are returned by your async task. But before you go to fix it, please consider using Loaders - they are asyncronous and made specifically for your purpouse - getting data for Fragment/Activity. Here is [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) for them. It looks like you might have a fair amount of refactoring to do if you want to implement them, but its well worth it - its the right way. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling notifyDataSetChanged() right after you start your Async thread, which hasn't populated your data. Call notifyDataSetChanged() after the data has been updated. Check out the examples in ApiDemos in the samples directory of the SDK.